# How to handle with Refs in react-redux connect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component wrapped by the react-redux "connect()" function and I have to manage the `<textarea>`  with Refs in React.

I'm using this version of react/react-redux/redux:
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"redux": "^4.0.5",

I've been googling all day, but I've seen everything that can help me.

Someone who uses hooks... *Ok, but at this stage I don't want to use them because I have to study them first*

Someone who said "you can put a ref on the wrapper component"... *Ok, but in my 8 hours of Google search I can't figure out how to do it?*

Is there someone who can help me understand and tell me how to write the right code?
Thanks

The code of my component is the following:

```
class EditorArea extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.textAreaRef = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {

        const {
            handleEditorChange,
            handleTextSelection,
            markdownText } = this.props;

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div id="editor-area">
                    <div id="text-area">
                        <textarea
                            id="editor"
                            ref={this.textAreaRef}
                            onChange={handleEditorChange}
                            onClick={() => handleTextSelection(this.textAreaRef)}
                            onSelect={() => handleTextSelection(this.textAreaRef)}
                            value={markdownText}
                            placeholder="Start here...">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )

    }
}

const madDispatch = dispatch => {
    return {
        handleEditorChange: (e) => dispatch(handleEditorChange(e)),
        handleTextSelection: () => dispatch(handleTextSelection())
    }

}

const mapState = state => {
    const { editingStatus, markdownText } = state.changeMarkdownText;

    return {
        editingStatus,
        markdownText,
    }
}


export default connect(
    mapState, madDispatch, null, { forwardRef: true }
)(EditorArea);
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention my needs and the problem: I need to access to the *selectionStart* and *selectionEnd* property of the `textarea` DOM object in my action-creator function but I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined"

This is my action-creator function:

```
export const handleTextSelection = (text) => {

    let newTextSelection = {};

    let startSelection = text.current.selectionStart;
    let endSelection = text.current.selectionEnd;

    newTextSelection.startSelection = startSelection;
    newTextSelection.endSelection = endSelection;
 
    return {
        type: MARKDOWN_TEXT_SELECTION,
        payload: newTextSelection
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you trying to store a html element in redux state (you shouldn't and probably can't)?

Comment: Thanks @HMR, I edited the question adding more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be with the `mapDispatch` function. You are not passing the ref as a parameter so it always dispatches `undefined` (empty param). Try this instead:

```
const madDispatch = dispatch => {
    return {
        handleEditorChange: (e) => dispatch(handleEditorChange(e)),
        //pass a param here: 
        handleTextSelection: (textAreaRef) => dispatch(handleTextSelection(textAreaRef))
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't seem to be the solution. Following your suggestion the error persists. I don't know how, even if I don't state the parameter in the function inside the MapDispatch, value is still passed.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Check out this sandbox I made: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-swartz-skqou
Your `handleTextSelection` seems to work just fine when not being passed as a dispatch prop. This is why I think it is related to the `mapDispatch` function.
Can you please share how the `mapDispatch` looks after the fix?

Comment: Thank you for your support and yes... you are right, the problem was related to the missing parameter in the function. By rewriting the code in the sandbox I found other problems and solved them.